# PHP search letter in array within array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array for example

```
 $name1 = "this is a string";
 $name2 = "another string";
 $arr1 = str_split($name1); //will return an array
 $arr2 = str_split($name2); //will return an array
```

Now what I want is to get rid all  the same letter from $arr1 to $arr2 and count the remaining.
example output:

```
oe //total count is 2
```

Comment: foreach($arr1 as $ar1 => $value1){
            foreach($arr2 as $ar2 => $value2){
                if($value1 == $value2){
                    $counter += 1;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: can you help me @chris85?

Comment: See answer, in the future please post what you have attempted. If that works for you please accept answer, if not please post issues encountered as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
$name1 = "this is a string";
$name2 = "another string";
$arr1 = str_split($name1); //will return an array
$arr2 = str_split($name2); //will return an array
$uniquecounts = array_count_values(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));
foreach($uniquecounts as $char => $count) {
    if($count == 1) {
        echo $char . ' is unique' . "\n";
    }
}
```

This combines your two arrays of individualized characters and compares them for only one occurrence of the character. Take a look at the manual for how to use `array_count_values`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php, in the future.

Output:

```
o is unique
e is unique
```

**Update:**

```
<?php
$name1 = "this is a string";
$name2 = "another string";
$arr1 = str_split($name1); //will return an array
$arr2 = str_split($name2); //will return an array
$uniquecounts = array_count_values(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));
$unqiues = '';
foreach($uniquecounts as $char => $count) {
    if($count == 1) {
        $unqiues .=  $char;
    }
}
echo $unqiues . ' ' . strlen($unqiues);
```

Output:

```
oe 2
```

Comment: let me try this @chris85..but how can I count the remaining?

Comment: `count the remaining,` what? All non-unique characters, occurrences of duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

```
function deduce($string1, $string2) {

    $result = array();

    foreach (count_chars($string2 . $string1, 1) as $i => $val) {
        if($val == 1) {
            $result[] = chr($i);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I've encountered this one before and what I did was this.